# Unable to "flutter run" due to failure to install SDK but flutter doctor runs fine

Tags: android, flutter

`flutter doctor` output on windows is

> C:\WINDOWS\system32> flutter doctor Doctor summary (to see all
>   details, run flutter doctor -v): 
>   [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0,> on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523], locale en-US) 
>   [√]Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
>   [√] Android Studio (version 3.2) [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version
>   1.31.1) 
>   [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

as you can see no issues found BUT flutter is detecting latest sdk installed as 27 when i have installed 28 already.

when i try to `flutter run` from vs code an app(first sample app from docs) i get this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\VSProjects\Flutter\myapp\android\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
>   > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   >     Failed to install the following SDK components:
>   >          build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
>   >      The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)

i tried changing the permission of the file to remove read-only access and still get the same error, i use the same sdk to build android apps with android studio(native) and visual studio(xamarin) just fine...i have the latest sdk version installed already so why is flutter giving me this error?

Can i downgrade my sdk requirement somehow?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have installed the Android SDK into `C:\Program Files (x86)`` which requires elevated privileges to write.  Android Studio seems to install it into `c:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` (not sure, I'm not a Windows user, just found a screenshot in a Google search)

Comment: ok i agree that was a mistake but i inherited this pc from a previous dev who left the company and i can't format it and reinstall the sdk elsewhere since i have to maintain apps in production, what is a possible solution?

Comment: You don't need to reformat. Install Android Studio and then change the environment variables so they point to the new Android SDK location. Rename the old location so it can't be found. Then test everything and if it works, delete the renamed directory.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i did it and it works! submit your comment as an answer and i'll accept it.never install sdks on c drive :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoudn't install the Android SDK into `C:\Program Files (x86)` which requires elevated privileges to write. 
Android Studio seems to install it into `C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` where the current user has sufficient privileges.