# Flutter Setup, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to set up my vs code to build flutter projects, 
but it is not finding my android sdk 28.

[image: problem]

but I do have the sdk 28 downloaded.

[image: sdk28]

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the path of the Android SDK in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you setup ANDROID_HOME in your PATH? Also check the build tools version in SDK Tools tab.

Comment: run flutter in vscode as admin(right click,run as administrator),i had the same issue. do not install android sdk on C drive. run flutter doctor in an elevated command prompt/powershell window and it will run fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to "flutter run" due to failure to install sdk but flutter doctor runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882032/unable-to-flutter-run-due-to-failure-to-install-sdk-but-flutter-doctor-runs-fi)